# How to pass function of subclass to scala map?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to pass a function with subclass parameter into a map (without success):

```
  trait GeneralRequestData
  case class MyRequestData(some: String) extends GeneralRequestData

  val myRequestDataToJsValue = (m: MyRequestData) => Json.obj("a" -> "b")

  val transformers: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, _ <: GeneralRequestData => JsValue] = new mutable.HashMap()
  transformers.put("myRequestData", myRequestDataToJsValue) // Error:(76, 37) type mismatch; found : myRequestDataToJsValue.type (with underlying type MyRequestData => play.api.libs.json.JsObject) required: _$2 transformers.put("myRequestData", myRequestDataToJsValue)
```

But I get the error:

> Error:(76, 37) type mismatch;  found   : myRequestDataToJsValue.type
>   (with underlying type MyRequestData => play.api.libs.json.JsObject) 
>   required: _$2   transformers.put("myRequestData",
>   myRequestDataToJsValue)

How can I fix that and pass that function with subclass parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a missing parens in the type definitions of `transformers`, it should be:

```
val transformers: mutable.Map[String, (_ <: GeneralRequestData) => JsValue] =
    new mutable.HashMap()
```

This tells the compiler that only the parameter of the function is a subclass of GeneralRequestData. Without the parens, the compiler expects the map values to be subclasses of `GeneralRequestData => JsValue`, but the value `myRequestDataToJsValue` isn't an instance of of this type since it's not accepting arbitrary `GeneralRequestData`.

Comment: Worth noting that while this is 100% correct, and fixes the immediate compilation issue, the result won't really be usable; A call like `transformers("myRequestData").apply(MyRequestData("Hi"))` won't compile because functions' input types are contravariant.